# Displaying Bootstrap Dismissible Alert

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, entity-framework, alert

I'm trying to display a success Bootstrap alert from my controller using ViewBag however, as soon as I navigate to the page the "close" button is showing up:

[image]

As soon as I save the changes it then displays the alert correctly:

[image]

How can I get rid of the close when navigating to the page?

Code:

***Controller***

```
            ViewBag.Message = "Definition Successfully Saved!";
            ViewBag.AlertClass = "alert alert-success alert-dismissible";
            ViewBag.AlertVisibility = "";
```

***View***

```
<div class="@ViewBag.AlertClass">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">close</button>
<h4 class="@ViewBag.AlertVisibility text-center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> @ViewBag.Message</h4>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bootstrap alert must be like this:

```
<div class="@ViewBag.AlertClass fade" role="alert">
  <h4 class="text-center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> 
       @ViewBag.Message</h4>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

So the **ViewBag.AlertClass** in C# code should be equal to:

```
ViewBag.AlertClass = "alert alert-success alert-dismissible show";
```

And as I can see you don't need **ViewBag.AlertVisibility** because the **show** class has that role.

Comment: Thank you! I tried your suggestion however, the alert is now not displaying at all. What do you think that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just put the fade to your Viewbag and to the view let class like this: class="@ViewBag.AlertClass"